# My search query in mongoDb is returning an empty list while using regex to search

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a database of users and I am trying to do a search by name in my database,
For eg: 
If my database has firstName as,
Alan
Alex
Arun
Alexender
Bob
Bill

And when I write my query

```
router.get('/friendSearch/:q', function (req, res) {
var result = [];
User.find({firstName: "/" + req.params.q + "/"}, function (err, list) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("In else");
        console.log(list);
    }
});
```

});

And pass "A" in my request params the query should return,
Alan
Alex
Arun
Alexender

But whereas I get an empty list. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$regex` instead:

```
{firstName: { '$regex' : req.params.q, '$options' : 'i' }}
```

you can remove the `$options` if you want. The i parameter is to search case insensitivity to match upper and lower cases. 
If you don't need the case insensitive option you can write  your query like that:

```
{firstName: { '$regex' : req.params.q}}
```

Here the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)